# Unable to update link in Power Point using VBA [LinkFormat.SourceFullName :Failed]

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I have been trying to use excel VBA code from this website https://exceloffthegrid.com/edit-links-in-powerpoint-using-vba/. To give some context, I already have a PowerPoint with chart and table that is link from excel file. I would like to update the link to another new excel file using the code below.

```
'Set the link to the Object Library: 
'Tools -> References -> Microsoft PowerPoint x.xx Object Library

Dim oldFilePath As String
Dim newFilePath As String
Dim sourceFileName As String
Dim pptApp As PowerPoint.Application
Dim pptPresentation As Object
Dim pptSlide As Object
Dim pptShape As Object

'The file name and path of the file to update
sourceFileName = "C:\File Path\Of Source File\File Name.pptx"

'The old file path as a string (the text to be replaced)
oldFilePath = "String of\File Path\To Be Replaced\Excel File.xlsx"

'The new file path as a string (the text to replace with)
newFilePath = "String of\New File Path\Excel File2.xlsx"

'Set the variable to the PowerPoint Application
Set pptApp = New PowerPoint.Application

'Make the PowerPoint application visible
pptApp.Visible = True

'Set the variable to the PowerPoint Presentation
Set pptPresentation = pptApp.Presentations.Open(sourceFileName)

'Loop through each slide in the presentation
For Each pptSlide In pptPresentation.Slides

    'Loop through each shape in each slide
    For Each pptShape In pptSlide.Shapes
   
        'Find out if the shape is a linked object or a linked picture
        If pptShape.Type = msoLinkedPicture Or pptShape.Type _
        = msoLinkedOLEObject Or pptShape.Type = msoLinkedChart Then

            'Use Replace to change the oldFilePath to the newFilePath
            pptShape.LinkFormat.SourceFullName = Replace(LCase _
            (pptShape.LinkFormat.SourceFullName), LCase(oldFilePath), newFilePath)

        End If
    Next
Next

pptPresentation.UpdateLinks

'Save, close and quit the application
pptPresentation.Save
pptPresentation.Close
pptApp.Quit


'Release the memory
Set pptApp = Nothing
Set pptPresentation = Nothing
Set pptSlide = Nothing
Set pptShape = Nothing

End Sub
```

I got an error. LinkFormat.SourceFullName : Failed. which is from this code

```
'Use Replace to change the oldFilePath to the newFilePath
           pptShape.LinkFormat.SourceFullName = Replace(LCase _
           (pptShape.LinkFormat.SourceFullName), LCase(oldFilePath), newFilePath)
```

Is there any setting that I have to do before running the code? Is there anyone have any idea?

Comment: Have you checked the result of `Replace(LCase _
            (pptShape.LinkFormat.SourceFullName), LCase(oldFilePath), newFilePath)` ? Is it what you expect?

Comment: Does the used `newFilePath`  (workkbook) have **exactly** the same sheet and chart **name**?

Comment: Following up on @FaneDuru's suggestion:  Try relinking to a copy of the original file in a different directory. If that works, then the problem is likely a difference between the files you're trying to link from/to.

Comment: Guyss thank you so much. It does make me rethink back ways to solve it. Cause it does work to my collogues laptop not mine. Don't really know what is the issues but I did have improvise the code a bit. .